# Decode Images - BLACKBERRY/Java

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me

Does anyone know how to decode an .png image on a sd card to bitmap on blackberry?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public class DisplayBitmaps extends UiApplication
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        DisplayBitmaps theApp = new DisplayBitmaps();       
        theApp.enterEventDispatcher();
    }

    public DisplayBitmaps()
    {     
        pushScreen(new DisplayBitmapsScreen());
    }    
}

final class DisplayBitmapsScreen extends MainScreen
{
    DisplayBitmapsScreen() {  
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000); // wait for the simulator SDCard to initialize in this example, on a phone this may take longer
            // for a better way see http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/1295814/How_To_-_Programmatically_determine_if_a_microSD_card_has_been_inserted.html?nodeid=1295868&vernum=0 
            FileConnection fc = (FileConnection) Connector.open("file:///SDCard/BlackBerry/pictures/image.png");
            if (fc.exists()) {
                byte[] image = new byte[(int) fc.fileSize()];
                InputStream inStream = fc.openInputStream();
                inStream.read(image);
                inStream.close();
                //EncodedImages are useful for further file manipulation, otherwise you can go straight to Bitmap
                //EncodedImage encodedImage = EncodedImage.createEncodedImage(image, 0, -1); 
                //Bitmap bitmap = encodedImage.getBitmap();
                Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmapFromBytes(image, 0, -1, 1);
                BitmapField bitmapField = new BitmapField(bitmap);
                fc.close();
                add(bitmapField);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) { System.out.println("EXCEPTION " + e); }
    }

    public void close()
    {  
        super.close();
    }   
}
```

The above code is an example of reading a png file from the SDCard into a Bitmap and displaying it in a BitmapField.

Cheers

Ray

Comment: Hi. I am unable to decode my png image file. It is giving me exception when I use the encodeImage.getBitmap.

Comment: I'd like to help so can you tell me what the exception is you are getting? I've updated the example so that it is a complete ui application and I've bypassed the EncodedImage stage (although it remains commented) EncodedImages are useful if you intend to do further manipulation.

Comment: Also the above code was tested with this png file: http://reboot.org.uk/images/image.png it would be nice to first rule out the file you're using as the issue.

Comment: I'm just curious if you gave this a go and what the error was, if any?